# Pinia access function inside click function using this

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I have a pinia store that runs some D3.js functions. Within a `.on()` function, I am trying to access `this.piniaAction`, not the `this` that is a SVG path.

For example:

```
export const useStore= defineStore('myStore', {
    actions: {
        piniaAction() {
            //Some stuff is done here
        },
        d3Action() {
            const svg = d3.select("#id")
            const group = svg.append("g")
            group.append("rect")
               .on("click", function(){
                   let myRect = d3.select(this) // This correctly gets the scoped svg element
                   this.piniaAction() //I want this to access the pinia action, not svg element
                }   
         }
     }
}
```

I can't find anything that helps me access the pinia action within the `.on()` function scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

learn about `this` in javascript it's a complicated concept

you can solve the problem using `arrow function` or `set temp variable`:

### arrow function

```
export const useStore= defineStore('myStore', {
    actions: {
        piniaAction() {
            //Some stuff is done here
        },
        d3Action() {
            const svg = d3.select("#id")
            const group = svg.append("g")
            group.append("rect")
               .on("click", () => {
                   let myRect = d3.select(this) // This correctly gets the scoped svg element
                   this.piniaAction() //I want this to access the pinia action, not svg element
                }   
         }
     }
}
```

#### temp var

```
export const useStore= defineStore('myStore', {
    actions: {
        piniaAction() {
            //Some stuff is done here
        },
        d3Action() {
            const $this = this

            const svg = d3.select("#id")
            const group = svg.append("g")
            group.append("rect")
               .on("click", function(){
                   let myRect = d3.select(this) // This correctly gets the scoped svg element
                   $this.piniaAction() //I want this to access the pinia action, not svg element
                }   
         }
     }
}
```